# How do I get my DatePicker Dialog to return a date and display it? Issue updating viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

A quick preface, I'm probably overlooking something rather simple but I'm willing to admit I'm not 100% sure of what I'm doing! The project I'm working on is a just for fun project to tinker around with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose by making an Android application.

So to my problem, I'm trying to use a DatePicker dialog using the vanpra compose-material-dialogs. I can get the dialog datepicker to appear but I can't get my selected date to return to my textfield I made after selecting the date from the dialog. It seems I'm running in to some issues updating the viewmodel correctly. Any help at all is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

---

Below is my DatePicker composable:

```
@Composable
fun TradeDatePicker(
    value: LocalDate,
    onValueChanged: (LocalDate) -> Unit,
    modifier:Modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        val dialogState = rememberMaterialDialogState()

        MaterialDialog(
            dialogState = dialogState,
            buttons = {
                positiveButton("OK")
                negativeButton("CANCEL")


            },
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            this.datepicker(onDateChange = onValueChanged)
        }
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
                    )
                .clip(ButtonShape) //clip keeps animation within box borders
                .clickable {
                    dialogState.show()
                }
        ){
            Row (
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp),
                    ){
                Text(
                    text = "Trade Date",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1F),
                )
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.DateRange,
                    contentDescription = "Select Date",
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my screen where you select the datepicker field to display the datepicker dialog, it seems I'm trying to pass a LocalDate to the viewmodel but it requires a long(that's how I thought the date got returned from the dialog, as a long):

```
@Composable
fun AddEditTradeScreen(

    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AddEditTradeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
    val tradesymbolState = viewModel.tradeSymbol.value
    val tradequantState = viewModel.tradeQuantity.value
    val tradeDateState = viewModel.tradeDate
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val value: LocalDate

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
        viewModel.eventFlow.collectLatest { event ->
            when(event){
                is AddEditTradeViewModel.UiEvent.ShowSnackbar ->{
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = event.message
                    )

                }
                is AddEditTradeViewModel.UiEvent.SaveTrade -> {
                    navController.navigateUp()

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.SaveTrade)
                },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Save, contentDescription = "Save Trade")
            }
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    ) {
        Column(

            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {



            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "Enter Your Tradeeee",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))


            TransparentHintTextField(
                text = tradesymbolState.text,
                hint = tradesymbolState.hint,
                onValueChange = {
                                viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredSymbol(it))
                },
                onFocusChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.ChangeSymbolFocus(it))
                },
                isHintVisible = tradesymbolState.isHintVisible,
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            TransparentHintTextField(
                text = tradequantState.text,
                hint = tradequantState.hint,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredQuantity(it))
                },
                onFocusChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.ChangeQuantityFocus(it))
                },
                isHintVisible = tradequantState.isHintVisible,
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                //modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            TradeDatePicker(
                value = LocalDate.now(),
                onValueChanged = {
                                 viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredTradeDate(it))
                                 },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )

        }
    }

}
```

---

This is my viewmodel that I'm trying to update:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddEditTradeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tradeUseCases: TradeUseCases,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel(){
    private val _tradeSymbol = mutableStateOf(
        TradeTextFieldState(
        hint = "Enter Trade Symobol"
    ))
    val tradeSymbol: State<TradeTextFieldState> = _tradeSymbol
    private val _tradeQuantity = mutableStateOf(
        TradeTextFieldState(
        hint = "Enter Number of Shares"
    ))
    val tradeQuantity: State<TradeTextFieldState> = _tradeQuantity
    private var _tradeDate : String? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }
    val tradeDate = { date: Long? ->
        _tradeDate = date?.toString()?:""
    }
    private val _eventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>()
    val eventFlow = _eventFlow.asSharedFlow()
    private var currentTradeId: Int? = null

    init{
        savedStateHandle.get<Int>("tradeId")?.let { tradeId ->
            if (tradeId != -1){
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    tradeUseCases.getTrade(tradeId)?.also { trade ->
                        currentTradeId = trade.id
                        _tradeSymbol.value = tradeSymbol.value.copy(
                            text = trade.tradeSymb,
                            isHintVisible = false
                        )
                        _tradeQuantity.value = tradeQuantity.value.copy(
                            text = trade.tradequant,
                            isHintVisible = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onEvent(event: AddEditTradeEvent){
        when(event){
            is AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredSymbol -> {
                _tradeSymbol.value = tradeSymbol.value.copy(
                    text = event.value
                )
            }
            is AddEditTradeEvent.ChangeSymbolFocus -> {
                _tradeSymbol.value = tradeSymbol.value.copy(
                    isHintVisible = !event.focusState.isFocused &&
                            tradeSymbol.value.text.isBlank()
                )
            }
            is AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredQuantity -> {
                _tradeQuantity.value = tradeQuantity.value.copy(
                    text = event.value
                )
            }
            is AddEditTradeEvent.ChangeQuantityFocus -> {
                _tradeQuantity.value = tradeQuantity.value.copy(
                    isHintVisible = !event.focusState.isFocused &&
                            _tradeQuantity.value.text.isBlank()
                )
            }
            is AddEditTradeEvent.EnteredTradeDate -> {
                _tradeDate.value = tradeDate.value.copy(
                    text = event.value
                )
            }
            is AddEditTradeEvent.SaveTrade -> {
                viewModelScope.launch{
                    try {
                        tradeUseCases.addTrade(
                            Trade(
                                tradeSymb = tradeSymbol.value.text,
                                tradequant= tradeQuantity.value.text,
                                timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                //tradestatus = "Long",
                                //color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.green
                                id = currentTradeId
                            )
                        )
                        _eventFlow.emit(UiEvent.SaveTrade)
                    } catch (e: InvalidTradeException){
                        _eventFlow.emit(
                            UiEvent.ShowSnackbar(
                                message = e.message ?: "Couldn't save trade"
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Lastly this is the event sealed class, not sure I'm using this correctly but in here for the "EnteredTradeDate" I declare it as a long and I'm not sure this is correct since I'm having trouble passing it from the screen to the viewmodel.

```
sealed class AddEditTradeEvent {
    data class EnteredSymbol(val value: String): AddEditTradeEvent()
    data class ChangeSymbolFocus(val focusState: FocusState): AddEditTradeEvent()
    data class EnteredQuantity(val value: String): AddEditTradeEvent()
    data class ChangeQuantityFocus(val focusState: FocusState): AddEditTradeEvent()
    data class EnteredTradeDate(val value: Long) : AddEditTradeEvent()
    data class ChangeDateFocus(val focusState: FocusState): AddEditTradeEvent()

    object SaveTrade: AddEditTradeEvent()


}
```

Comment: In your current code the `tradeDateState` is not used (read) anywhere, so unless you omitted some code, that would be the reason why you don't see the change taking effect anywhere.